# Error while loading data from mysql to redis cluster

Tags: mysql, go, redis-cluster

i'm new to both Redis and Go Language, so just bear with me. I'm trying to load some mysql data to the redis cluster.

I'm using this code from gitHub:[Go program to load mysql data to redis](https://github.com/xiaoao/load2redis)

Using this, I'm able to load mysql data to a redis instance that is acting as a **standalone redis server(127.0.0.1:7000)**.

But when i'm trying to load the same data to the nodes in a redis cluster(having 3 masters(127.0.0.1:7000,7001,7002)), i'm getting the following exception:

```
hmset error: MOVED 12937 127.0.0.1:7001
```

My redis.config for node running on port 7000:

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-7000.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
protected-mode no
```

Can somebody suggest why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#moved-redirection The node redirected you. You need to reissue the query to the node specified (127.0.0.1:7001).

Comment: @Gavin: How is it possible to do that? According to the code i can only load the db data, to 1 node at an instance(I can provide only 1 host ip and port at a time). Is there no way by which the client can move from node to node doing insertion automatically?

Comment: Give [this](https://github.com/chasex/redis-go-cluster) library a look.